# select an element next to current element HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to parsing html page. I want to select a collection of tag h3 then loop through it, and for each h3 element, i want to select a element right next to it. Here is my sample Html:

```
<h3>Somthing here</h3>
<ul>list of something</ul>

<h3>Somthing here</h3>
<ul>list of something</ul>

<h3>Somthing here</h3>
<ul>list of something</ul>

<h3>Somthing here</h3>
<ul>list of something</ul>

<h3>Somthing here</h3>
<ul>list of something</ul>
```

I know how to select collection of h3, but i don't have any ideas how to select ul next to each

Answer (score 2):

If current node is `h3`, use this XPath:

```
following-sibling::ul[1]
```

It selects 1<sup>st</sup> `ul` sibling.

Comment: you mean something like: h3Node.selectSingleNode("following-sibling::ul[1]")?