# Html Agility Pack - – Extract Node with “empty” class Attribute OR Select a PAIR of nodes (one and its immediate following node)

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I need to extract pairs of nodes from a html code (either HtmlDocument or a List of HtmlNodes).

The problem is I need to select a node (from a List or a HtmlDocument, doesn’t matter I’ll pick the best solution) that has a class Attribute but no value at all (see pictures).

Another (better solution, I think) would be to select the “” node and its immediate following-sibling::li[1] (link #2) and it’s probably what I will do for this part of my program.
Link #2 seems to help a bit but I don’t know how to use it in a way like “get all  nodes AND its first following-sibling”.

I’d like 2 things: 
-   A bit of code to get “one node by class AND its first following node”, I haven’t used XPathes (or w/e it’s called) yet so I’m not used to 
-   If it’s possible, a way to get a “node which has the class Attribute but NO VALUE”

The thing is, I’ll have to select HtmlNode with “valueless“ class later and I’m looking for a way to do it. The idea (if it’s still not clear enough) would be something like:

```
var r = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("li").Where(d => d.Attributes["class"].Value.Equals(NULL)); //I’m not sure about the [enter image description here][1].Value.Equals() ^^’
```

Links: 
-   [How to get next 2 nodes in HTML + HTMLAgilitypack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802453/how-to-get-next-2-nodes-in-html-htmlagilitypack) 
But I never used this before (I could use this to select the “” node and its immediate following (Not going to use this, way too spooky)

- [select an element next to current element HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813877/select-an-element-next-to-current-element-htmlagilitypack) 
  I was planning on using this BUT I never used xpath for htmldoc yet (looking into it now)

Pictures:

[sample code of what I'd like to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0fxQ.jpg)
Trying to add 2 pictures : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B11P.jpg)

### Update

Okay so, with Hung Cao's help I was able to select the

```
<li class>
```

nodes.

Now, what I would like to do (it's what I first explained but it wasn't very clear, even for me ^^ so I'll try to use a specific example), is to select "pairs" of nodes, more precisely one specific node and its immediate first sibling. I have :

`<li class="A">...</>` => first pair
`<li class="B">...</>` => first pair
`<li class="A">...</>` => second pair
`<li class="B">...</>`=> second pair

And I would like to end up with like a Collection or an Array containing pairs of class A/class B (Actually, I'm using a c# class which is basically A's Content, and in it there is an array in which I store B class's elements).

tl;dr: I'd like something along the lines of 
`public List<Pair> ExtractPairs(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc){`

```
List<Pair> pairs = new List<>();

foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='A']")) {
```

`Pair pair = new Pair(node,node`
's first-sibling here (which will always be a `<li class="B">`) `);`

```
pairs.add(pair);


}

return pairs;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TBH, I am not quite understand your question clearly but here is my attempt to answer it.

> A bit of code to get “one node by class AND its first following node”,
>   I haven’t used XPathes (or w/e it’s called) yet so I’m not used to -

```
public static bool HasClass(this HtmlNode node, params string[] classValueArray)
{
    var classValue = node.GetAttributeValue("class", "");
    var classValues = classValue.Split(' ');
    return classValueArray.All(c => classValues.Contains(c));
}
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("li").FirstOrDefault(_ => _.HasClass("classname")).NextSibling;
```

> If it’s possible, a way to get a “node which has the class Attribute
>   but NO VALUE”

```
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("li").Where(_ => string.IsNullOrEmpty(_.GetAttributeValue("class", "")))
```

Comment: Indeed I realize it may not have been 100% clear.
But yeah, your second answer seems to be what I was looking for. 

For the first part, I wanted to "easily" retrieve the bits <li class="directory"> AND <li class> (the one right after it, so the first sibling if I'm not mistaken), but thank to your help I'll try that and, in worst case scenario, go for 2 loops, one looking for the first <li> (directories) and another one looking for the <li class> and eventually I'll just use it like "directoryArray[0]" goes with "liArray[0]". 

Thanks for the help, I'll give an update asap.

Comment: Ok so, as I said previously, I used your 2nd bit of code and it does the job !

I'm able to retrieve the the "<li class>" nodes and that's already of huge help. 

Thank you

Comment: It helps me one one of the 2 problems yes, and thank you for that.

I updated my question hoping for the second answer I'm looking for but if I don't get an answer by tomorrow I'll mark your answer as accepted. I can always do the 2 loops I talked about :)

Comment: In the end, I did what I said earlier and used a loop to find the <li class> and I use ".NextSibling.Descendants()" and I'm able to get my "pairs" ^^